# Docusign aks for login when my .net application run

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a .net MVC sample application. now when I start application first time it will call DocuSign API and give me access code and use that I get account id and URL. I then stop it an run it again I need to follow the same procedure, so is there any option to get or authenticate application once. See below code. note I am using trial sandbox environment.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(RestApiUrl);
            DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

            //Initiate the browser session to the Authentication server
            //so the user can login.
            string accountServerAuthUrl = apiClient.GetAuthorizationUri(client_id, redirect_uri, true, stateOptional);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(accountServerAuthUrl); // This always open in browser docusign login

            return View();
        }
```

return url...

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetRes()
        {
            AccessCode = Request.QueryString["code"];

            // state is app-specific string that may be passed around for validation.
            StateValue = Request.QueryString["state"];

            // Signal the main test that the response has been received.
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
        }
```

using code get account id

```
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(RestApiUrl);
            DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

            string accessToken = apiClient.GetOAuthToken(client_id, client_secret, true, AccessCode);

            // login call is available in the authentication api 
            AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
            LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

            // parse the first account ID that is returned (user might belong to multiple accounts)
            AccountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;
            BaseUri = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].BaseUrl;
```

Is there any other application authantication process or sample code would be help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying ot use User Application instead of Service Integration. What you are trying is called as [Authorization Code Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html). In `Authorization Code Grant`, you need to consent from the user by opening the URL, once consent in given to you then you will use code returned in the URL in DocuSign's OAUTH2 API to generate `AccessToken` and `RefreshToken`. `AccessToken` is `short-lived` and `will expire` in few hours, once `AccessToken` expires then you have to use `RefreshToken` to generate a new set of `AccessToken` and `RefreshToken`. `Refresh tokens` typically have a `longer lifetime` than access tokens, but they `do expire`. To request a refresh token with the longest possible lifetime (depending on account and system security policies) use `extended` scope when you make the initial authentication request via URL. Before making a call to the DocuSign API, check the current time against the expiration time. If it is within the threshold, use the refresh token to get a new access token. If the response to the refresh operation is an error, you will need to repeat the initial authentication flow by asking user to login again.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign API has two Major Authentication modes at present:

1. Classic X-DocuSign-Authentication w/wo SOBO (Works, Sunset date unknown - Great for "Service" apps that don't have interaction with users)
2. OAuth2 - Bearer Token w/wo SOBO (Works, DocuSign Recommended methodology, can be onerous on service applications and dev ops - no way to set it and forget it that I am aware of)

Both are covered here for reference (Thanks to Amit K Bist) https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html

First, you will want a system sender account for the application aka "Big Corp" to be the "Authenticated System user". Then you will Send On Behalf Of (SOBO) of the other users that can "Send", not user that can just view.

I do NOT recommend using a "Prod" Trial account, please make sure you are using a "Demo Sandbox".

You will need to turn on the SOBO feature discussed here https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/sobo.html

As a reminder, you can you capture exact JSON/SOAP request posted by your API calls by following steps explained at this DocuSign support article https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

Comment: Classic X-DocuSign-Authentication is not recommended now

Comment: @AmitKBist While you work at DocuSign, please understand, what works vs what is recommended are two very different issues for developers needing to meet a deadline. Also, I am sure you aware of many Big Co that are still using and will keep using this as they don't have the budget to willy nilly change code because DocuSign "recommends" the new thing. I try to recommend both and let Developer's choose what works for the timeline and budget they have. I don't work at DocuSign anymore so I can truly speak my mind :-)

Comment: it available on our [DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html) itself. For last many months we have stopped suggesting `Legacy Auth Header` for any new integrations, and also working with existing customer to move to new way.

Comment: @AmitKBist I hear you, you are a good soldier, however, please state the Date (you can't I suspect) when the product group will stop supporting the "Legacy" Classic X-DocuSign-Authentication ? If you can't, then it is just a goal, just like shutting down API version 2, checkbox customer using Integrations without integrator keys, and now classic. So in my mind Stack Overflow is NOT about what marketing and product is pushing, it is about what works. Now if you want to tout all the "good valid" reasons to use one over the other, preach on, if not, don't lead with "thou shalt" vs what works :-)

Comment: OAUTH is an industry standard, and the controls is with user to revoke the access anytime directly from his/her DS Account when user does not want to continue with the vendor application. Whereas in Legacy, it is more like Hard Coding passing username and password in all the API calls, which is definitely not secure. Also anytime a DocuSign Admin wants to add multi factor authentication for its users then using OAUTH flow only MFA will come into picture while user is authenticating any App to call API on user's behalf.

Comment: @AmitKBist Now your talking! FYI - Both can be revoked as you know under connected apps because the "KEY" is used the same in both, only the methods and header are different. Thanks for the good discussion, I do believe it helps DocuSign Developers understand "WHY" when choosing an architecture and related pattern for a platform API. We should get coffee soon! Have a great weekend.